# Using SecureString with WebRequest

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, httpwebrequest, securestring

I trying to obtain an access token from Azure using PowerShell. Which I have got working as I need it to. However I am concerned that I have a client secret stored and processed as a string for much of the time.

This is the code I am running so far -

```
$body = "&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + $Config.ClientId
$body += "&resource=" + [uri]::EscapeDataString("https://vault.azure.net") 
$body += "&client_secret=" + $Config.client_secret      

$uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + $Config.TenantId.tenantId + '/oauth2/token?'

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body
```

The `$Config.client_secret` is saved as a SecureString that I have to convert to a normal string to send into `Invoke-WebRequest` This seems horribly insecure.

I realise that this is very likely impossible in PowerShell, so I have been trying to find an alternative in C#, but as yet I've not found anything.

Is there a way to pass a SecureString in the above Post request? (I'm not specifically looking for code, just a pointer as to whether its possible to do - once I know what I'm looking for I can figure the code out!)

Comment: It is a requirement of a oauth protocol that you provide a client secret value. Note that you do this post over https so it is a secure call.

Comment: @SergeyL I realise that, my question is concerned with how to pass a securestring in a Post request, in as secure a manner as possible. (i.e. I am trying to avoid having a password converted to a string - which is what SecureStrings should help to avoid)